# Excel VBA is blocking the Ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a .xlam file that holds some macro's. I use these macro's as a button in my ribbon. 
Most of these macro's are opening other Excel sheets. But whenever I use that macro's the ribbon is blocking, I can not use any of the tabs or the buttons in those tabs.

Does anyone know why this happens? This is an example of the code that I added as a macro in the ribbon.

```
Sub OpenBureauplanning()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Path As String
    Path = "J:\Planning\Bureauplanning\"

    Dim openfile As String
    openfile = Path & "Bureauplanning.xlsm"

    Workbooks.Open (openfile)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

After the replies from Dai. I removed the part "application.screenupdating" then its working fine.

In a different code, I use a form to determine which file needs to be opened. I also use that code in my ribbon.

That code is this:

```
Sub OpenProjectplanning()
Open_projectplanning.Show
End Sub
```

When running this code these forms get opened. In this form, people fill in the project number from the file that needs to be opened.

[image]

When the button "openen" is pressed the following code is starting:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Path As String
    Path = "J:\Planning\Projecten\"

Dim File As String
File = TextBox1.Text

Dim openfile As String
    openfile = Path & File & ".xlsm"

    Workbooks.Open (openfile)

Unload Me

End Sub
```

When opening the project file this code is automatically running on open:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planning").Activate

End Sub
```

After running these codes, the ribbon is blocked.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking" the ribbon? Is it visually obscured or is the UI just frozen?

Comment: What happens when you use the VBA debugger with your macro? Do you see any runtime errors happening?

Comment: I suspect that `Application.ScreenUpdating` is causing the Excel UI to be unresponsive (as it's meant to) but an error happens inside `Workbooks.Open` which causes `ScreenUpdating = True` to be skipped. Try adding an `On Error GoTo ...` statement that will ensure that `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` is always set before `OpenBureauplanning` returns.

Comment: @Dai i don't get any errors when running the code

Comment: @Dai if i remove application.screenupdating it still happens

Comment: In which case there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted - you need to show us the code inside `Bureauplanning.xlsm`.

Comment: @dai Thanks i did some more testing with that section of code and it works now. But i have a different code which is more complex. After running this code the ribbon is also blocked. I edited my message above and placed the codes where I run through in the message.